# How to search for an email in windows explorer

Tags: email, search-engine, windows-explorer

I need to search for an email in file content in windows explorer.
So I tried:
type in search box

```
"abc@domain.com"
```

Event I put it in phrase or choose advance and search in file content, search for that phrase, it always show many result which I check by opening in Notepad++ and search for that email then it shows no result.

So it looks like windows explorer will search for file that contains "abc" AND "domain" not file that contain the whole string "abc@domain.com".

So how could I define my search string so it could understand I am search for that email address please ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

just use crtl + f and search "abc@domain.com"

Hope that helps

Comment: It gave the same results. There is no difference from what I mentioned above and what you said.